# Right Pattern to design Parent-Child class

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, design-patterns

How to design Parent-Child class.

Note:Here Parent is not base class rather it shows one to many relationship.

Approach "A"

```
public class Company
{
   public int CompanyID;
   ...
   public IList<Branch> Branches;
}

public class Branch
{
}
```

Appraoch "B"

```
public class Company
{   
   public int CompanyID;
   ...
}

public class Branch
{
   public int CompanyID; //which represents company object
}
```

Finalized UI Design of Branch Screen:=

Displaying in Tree-view for view screen:-

```
Company A
    Branch 1
    Branch 2
Company B
    Branch 3
    Branch 4
    Branch 5
```

Add/Edit Screens(2 separate screen):-

```
Company - Company Drop-down
other attributes of Branch
```

1) If we see View screen then Approach "A" looks fine and if we see Add/Edit screen Approach "B" looks fine.

2) while using Approach "A", when I have to return branch data then I have to actually return Company type instead of Branch Type:

```
Company GetBranch(int BranchID)
```

3) Our DB design is based on Approach "B" where Branch Table stores CompanyID

Can somebody suggest what is the good approach to go with ?

Comment: Why store the back-reference to the parent using an Id? Why not refer to the parent object instead?

Comment: That is not my concern yet. I can change it to company object if required.

Comment: My first priority is to finalize which approach should I go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO there is no "right" to do this. It all depends on how do you plan to use and store/retrieve the data.

Storing the Branchs under the Companies my cause huge traffic overhead (as you will allways pass ALL the branches even when all you care about is the company or specific branch) , using ID alone my cause additional "queries" in order to load all the relevnat data.
I would  go with implementation similar to how the Entity framework works:

I would have branch and company id repository and keep the navigational properties (Comany.Branches, Branch.Company) and have a function that fills the properties that would be called only when needed.

For example you can have `GetCompany(id)` function that returns only the company and `GetCompanyWithBranche(id,int? brandchid)` that will return the company object filled with its branches (or single branch if id is specified). This way you will be able to determinate how much data to retrive.