# Properly create relationship, many to one or one to many

Tags: c#, .net, domain-driven-design

I have two entities `Article` and `Brand`. 
one article belongs one brand and one brand can have many articles

so my question is this right perception of creating relationship

> In any point of time one article belongs to one brand and one brand holds many articles

knowing that this is

**`one to many via Article side`**

and

**`many to one via Brand side`**

So when saying which relationship is between `Article` and `Brand` is it correct to say **one to many** or **many to one** or should I emphasize which side relationship describe ?

Comment: Are you looking something like this ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905297/right-pattern-to-design-parent-child-class

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for theoretical answer then your question itself has an answer.

`Actually It depends on which side you are looking at`

For Example:
If you are looking via Article screen its one to many and if you are looking via Brand screen its many to one.

Answer (score 1):

If you to properly understand relationships between entities you should ask yourself two questions

1. How many brands should article have
2. How many articles should brand have

All realtionships are defined into

1. One to one
2. One to many
3. Many to many

Someone can say that there is many to one relationship but in reality there is only one to many relationship observed from reverse perspective.

Answer (score 0):

you can say either ways specifying if it is article-brand relationship then one to many and if it is brand-article many to one relationship